# Remove leading/trailing stopwords in Python list

Tags: python, list, stop-words

I have a small problem that requires to remove leading and trailing stopwords with the below solution using `while` loop:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

cached_stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

text = "a the sky is the blue the a a"
tokens = text.split(" ")

start_idx, end_idx = 0, len(tokens) - 1
while start_idx < len(tokens) and tokens[start_idx] in cached_stop_words:
    start_idx += 1
while end_idx >= 0 and tokens[end_idx] in cached_stop_words:
    end_idx -= 1

new_tokens = tokens[start_idx: end_idx + 1] if start_idx < end_idx + 1 else []
print(new_tokens)
```

The output of this code is a list of tokens `['sky', 'is', 'the', 'blue']` because the leading and trailing stopwords are removed. Please note that the token `the` is not removed since it's in the middle of non-stopwords `sky` and `blue`. The code works but not efficiently. Can we use regular expression or any optimized approach for this problem?

Comment: Given, that your code works, It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: As far as I know `stopwords.words` returns a `list`? You could cast it into a `set` to speed up the lookup: `cached_stop_words = set(stopwords.words("English"))`.

Comment: Thanks Timus. That's a great suggestion.